# How To Transfer Money Online So The Other Person In Another Country Receives It In Cash?

Tags: credit-card, currency, cash, international-transfer, israel

We all are familiar with famous international money transfer service - Western Union. Most use their locally available branches in their country to send money so the other person receives money in cash.

What I was wondering about is sending money **online** using funding sources such as credit card or other payment processors like PayPal to send money without physically visiting local branch and wait in queue so the other person receives it in **cash** but **without** being obligated to have online account of respective service - all from the comfort of your own home and save time

Unfortunately Western Union only accepts credit cards issued in specific countries *(one of which is USA by the way)* albeit my country *(Israel)* is not accepted, at least yet. If anybody can suggest similar credible and dependable service, I would appreciate the suggestion along with any other useful information you wish to share.

Comment: What country are you trying to send money to?

Comment: Estonia is the country I want to send money to.

Comment: Does Western Union accept US-issued prepaid cards? I think you should be able to purchase one with relative ease.

Comment: Where in Israel would I find US-issued prepaid card?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such service. The [Israeli Credit Cards law](http://www.myrights.co.il/%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91/) is such that it will be very easy to defraud credit card issuers if such service was available. Check with [the postal company](http://www.israelpost.co.il/content.nsf/pages/avara?opendocument) if they allow doing it through their bank account, although their online service was horrible last time I checked.

This is obviously country-dependent as laws differ from place to place.

Comment: Littleadv, can you provide references to back up your experiences?  Link to the law, the appropriate postal office page, or blogs talking about this?

Comment: Added a link with explanations, doubt it will be relevant to much people here though. My point was that it is highly localized and dependent on the local laws. That is also why I criticized Sun's answers.